# SSLHandshakeException in Eclipse Temurin JRE8 Alpine container for self-signed certificate

Tags: docker, java-8, ssl-certificate, alpine-linux

TL;DR: After installing my CA in a Docker container from image `eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine` I still get *javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure* when accessing an URL with a certificate signed by the CA.

I'm currently trying to upgrade one of my applications from base image `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` (which was last updated three years ago and still runs Java `1.8.0_212`) to `eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine` (with Java `1.8.0_332`).

I'm using self-signed certificates for some other applications that this application communicates with. So in the current setup I copy my CA-certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and call `update-ca-certificates`.

In `eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine` I have to do some more steps: The package `ca-certificates` is not installed by default. Also the package `java-cacerts` is not installed anymore (which makes sense when `ca-certificates` is not, of course). So in my Dockerfile I install both and also link the `cacerts` file, that is created by `java-cacerts`, to the Java home directory:

```sh
apk add -U ca-certificates java-cacerts && ln -sf /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/
```

Afterwards I copied my CA certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and called `update-ca-certificates`. When I look at `/etc/ssl/certs/` I see the link to my certificate in there. And the file `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` is also updated (at least the modification date changes).

Accessing any application with a certificate signed by the CA works with `wget` now. But still fails from a Java application.

If I do the exact same thing with the image `eclipse-temurin:11-jre-alpine` it works in Java as well.

Any help is much appreciated!

### How I Tested

1. start a container from image `eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine`

```sh
docker run --rm -it --name temurin_8alpine_test --entrypoint /bin/sh eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine
```

2. install `ca-certificates` and `java-cacerts` in container

```sh
apk add -U ca-certificates java-cacerts && ln -sf /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/
```

3. copy certificate to running container

```sh
docker cp /path/to/my/CA-certificate.pem temurin_8alpine_test:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

4. update certificate stores in container

```sh
update-ca-certificates
```

this warns *ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping*, which is ok (https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/30)

5. test with `wget`

```
/ # wget https://my.internal.app
Connecting to my.internal.app (1.2.3.4:443)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |**********************************************************|  1087  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

6. download, compile and upload `SSLPoke`

```sh
wget -q https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/117455/SSLPoke.java -O /tmp/SSLPoke.java
# make sure to use Java 8 compiler or use --target 8
javac /tmp/SSLPoke.java -d /tmp/
docker cp /tmp/SSLPoke.class temurin_8alpine_test:/
```

SSLPoke from https://matthewdavis111.com/java/poke-ssl-test-java-certs/

7. test with `SSLPoke` in container

```
/ # java SSLPoke google.com 443
Successfully connected
/ # java SSLPoke my.internal.app 443
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:818)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1180)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
        at SSLPoke.main(SSLPoke.java:23)
/ #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some deeper digging and some help by @JockX I found the actual issue: Java8 Temurin does not support any of the SSL cipher suites my internal app requires.

As the same goes for @JockX's example https://jockx.net I'll use that site for the example:

All ciphers supported by the site use *eliptic curves*:

```
user@nb [~]
-> % nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 jockx.net
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-16 17:32 CEST
Nmap scan report for jockx.net (172.67.206.34)
Host is up (0.022s latency).
Other addresses for jockx.net (not scanned): 104.21.37.83 2606:4700:3034::ac43:ce22 2606:4700:3034::6815:2553

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256-draft (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.09 seconds
user@nb [~]
-> %
```

When you look at the supported cipher suites of the Java installation in a container running with image `eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine`, then you get the following:

```
/ # java SSLCipherSuites
Supported Cipheruites:
* TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
/ #
```

I compiled the following short *script* with Java 8 and copied it to the container:

```java
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class SSLCipherSuites {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        String[] cipherSuites = sslsocketfactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        System.out.println("Supported CipherSuites:");
        for (String cipherSuite : cipherSuites) {
                System.out.println("* " + cipherSuite);
        }
    }
}
```

If I do the same in a container running with image `eclipse-temurin:11-jre-alpine` I get the following:

```
/ # java SSLCipherSuites
Supported CipherSuites:
* TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
/ #
```

https://www.google.com supports a lot more ciphers and hence accessing it works from `eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine`

```
user@nb [~]
-> % nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 google.com
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-16 17:47 CEST
Nmap scan report for google.com (216.58.212.174)
Host is up (0.024s latency).
Other addresses for google.com (not scanned): 2a00:1450:4001:802::200e
rDNS record for 216.58.212.174: ams15s22-in-f174.1e100.net

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|   TLSv1.3:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: C

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.96 seconds
user@nb [~]
-> %
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: For those who can't just upgrade to 11, it seems like the `:8-jre` (not Alpine) version also support more ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about ca-cert related packages, and directly update `cacerts` file of JRE powering the container. Use `keytool`, which is part of the image you are using:

```
/opt/java/openjdk/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias mycert -file /my-ca-cert.crt
```

Depending on the format of the ca-certificate file you are adding, you may need to convert it to the format supported by `keytool`. For example a PEM file with the lines like these:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

may be converted with `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -in my-cert.pem -text -out my-ca-cert.crt
```

If to be done inside the container, the requrired package is `openssl`:

```
apk add openssl
```

Comment: I'd really like to have the certificate in the system as well, so I'm not running in issues when I need to debug in the container. Nevertheless I tried it and this does not work either. I'm starting to suspect, that Java is not using the `cacerts` file I think it uses... Is there a way of finding out which file is used?

Comment: @MaxN. well, after a closer inpection, I realized your problem is of a different nature, and this answer is just proposing to do what you are doing in a different way, but to exactly the same effect. This is not an untrusted ca exception. In that case the you would expect: `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException` in your error stack trace. I am facing the same exception with the same image on some legit production site as well, where non-alpine temurin8-jre works fine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _legit production site_? One with a _real_ certificate? I think I don't have problems with those. At least not with Google.

Comment: Yes, a real, valid certificate (by cloudflare) on a publicly available domain: https://jockx.net

Comment: Also, answering part of your question: you can print loads of debug info, if you execute java command with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` flag. E.g.: `java -Djavax.net.debug=all SSLPoke host 443 2>&1 | grep "CA"`

Comment: Both my internal and your public site have in common, that they require TLS1.2. Maybe that's the issue? Google does not and seems to work.

Comment: I checked with `openssl s_client -connect <DOMAIN>:443 -tls1_1` which returns a certificate for `google.com` but not for `jockx.net` and also not for my internal app.

Comment: Ok. I think I found the actual issue: Java8 Temurin does not support any TLS cipher suites with elliptical curve. But both your and my site require those (see `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <DOMAIN>`).