# Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder error in my Apache Ignite cluster which is deployed in AKS

Tags: azure-aks, ignite

I am spinning up an ignite cluster in AKS using official documentation https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/azure-deployment

I am using the below files to create the resources

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.serviceName
  name: ignite-service
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.namespace
  namespace: ignite
  labels:
    app: ignite
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thinclients
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
  # Optional - remove 'sessionAffinity' property if the cluster
  # and applications are deployed within Kubernetes
  #  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    # Must be equal to the label set for pods.
    app: ignite
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

created service account with cmd `kubectl create sa ignite -n ignite`

cluster-role.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ignite
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ignite
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite
```

deployment.yaml

```
# An example of a Kubernetes configuration for pod deployment.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # Cluster name.
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  # The initial number of pods to be started by Kubernetes.
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100000
      containers:
        # Custom pod name.
      - name: ignite-node
        image: apacheignite/ignite:2.14.0
        env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
        ports:
        # Ports to open.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port
        - containerPort: 49112 # dafault JMX port
        - containerPort: 10800 # thin clients/JDBC driver port
        - containerPort: 8080 # REST API
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /ignite/config
          name: config-vol
      volumes:
      - name: config-vol
        configMap:
          name: ignite-config
```

node-configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                        <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                        <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

created configmap using cmd  `kubectl create configmap ignite-config -n ignite --from-file=node-configuration.xml`

the pods are up and running. However I am getting below error

```
[07:22:28,352][SEVERE][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries) [maxTimeout=0]
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:81)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2057)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1992)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1283)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1120)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:472)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2212)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:278)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:1089)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1766)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1147)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1757)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1679)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1121)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1015)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:840)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:710)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:679)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.kubernetes.connection.KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.getServiceAddresses(KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.java:123)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:76)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.kubernetes.connection.KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.getServiceAddresses(KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.java:111)
        ... 21 more
```

I see that the public IP has been assigned to the ignite-service loadbalancer. can anyone please help me with the issue.

Thanks in advance!!

I have tried  a couple solutions in the net but they did not get me anywhere.

Comment: i have never tried ignite however by any chance it need the SSL cert or any other setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be related to a base image change in Apache Ignite starting from 2.14.

I suggest the following:

- check if switching to [GridGain image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gridgain/community) would resolve the issue.
- replace TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder with other finder, for example [JdbcIpFinder](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/jdbc/TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder.html) or [TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#static-ip-finder)

Comment: Hi Alexandr Shapkin, this works. Thank you so much. I am able to activate the cluster as well after running the script  opt/gridgain/bin/control.sh --set-state ACTIVE --yes

Answer (score 2):

First of all please clarify the exact version of your ignite image.

Most probably issue is with TLS ciphers. In other words there is no intersection between ciphers set that available in your JRE in ciphers set that required by remote server (k8s API).

To find out source of problem you can try following sequence:

**I) Verify that k8s API is available from container and gives proper responses**

```
# Get shell of particular kubernetes container
kubectl -n ignite-namespace exec --stdin --tty ignite-cluster-5cd44847cb-cpshh -- /bin/bash

# Point to the internal API server hostname
APISERVER=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443

# Path to ServiceAccount token
SERVICEACCOUNT=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount

# Read this Pod's namespace
NAMESPACE=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/namespace)

# Read the ServiceAccount bearer token
TOKEN=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/token)

# Reference the internal certificate authority (CA)
CACERT=${SERVICEACCOUNT}/ca.crt

SERVICE_NAME=ignite

# Add cURL utility for querying k8s API
apk add curl

# Query available nodes (you should get json output with list of addrs):
curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET ${APISERVER}/api/v1/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/endpoints/${SERVICE_NAME}
```

If you get proper json output with proper addresses you k8s config is fine and you can proceed to verification of SSL/TLS communication.

Note that depending on container permissions yo might not be able to install curl (try to use wget in this case). If this won't work go to step II.

**II) Check SSL/TLS**

The best source of information is java SSL debug logs `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. Enable them via JVM_OPTS variable of ignite pod:

```
- name: JVM_OPTS
  value: '-server -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ...'
```

After applying this option you would see in logs verbose info about SSL communication between **ignite ip finder** and **k8s API**. Try to find ServerHello and ClientHello messages like:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2023-01-12 13:31:52.975 GMT|ClientHello.java:575|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "D3 A5 D8 64 47 13 05 10 AB F4 B8 73 80 92 7C 76 5F 3E D9 AC 4E 09 52 29 A4 78 B0 80 74 9A BA E4",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), ...]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, ...]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, ...]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2]
    }
  ]
}
```

According to this `ClientHello` message k8s API support TLSv1.2 and some set of ciphers (see `"cipher suites"` field). Find corresponding `ServerHello` message, sent by JVM and compare ciphers set. If there is no common ciphers this is a root cause.

Possible steps to workaround:

1. Depending on underlying JVM you could try to play around `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` JVM property.
2. Move to images build on top of different openjdk e.g. `ignite:2.14.0-jdk11`  (it has way bigger set of available ciphers)
3. Build custom ignite image on top of different base JDK image (current ignite image built on top of `eclipse-temurin:$JDK_VERSION-jre-alpine` so try non-alpine images like `eclipse-temurin:$JDK_VERSION-jre`)
4. If possible you can also refer to Azure support for clarification about k8s API ciphers set.

PS. To get a set of supported ciphers you could try to use nmap utility as well:

```
apk add nmap nmap-scripts
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Useful links:

[1] https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception-r

[2] [SSLHandshakeException in Eclipse Temurin JRE8 Alpine container for self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72186823/sslhandshakeexception-in-eclipse-temurin-jre8-alpine-container-for-self-signed-c)

Comment: Hi @solveMe, I am not able to install the curl in the pod due to the permission issue. However the solution which Alexandr Shapkin suggested worked. I have changed the docker image and then ran the script mentioned in the comment under his answer for which activated the ignite cluster.  Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi @solveMe, this reply helped. I have changed the base image to gnite:2.15.0-jdk11, and this issue is resolved. Thank you.